# ng-include as modal first reference works, second reference fails

Tags: angularjs

My Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xrzhG9NqYfv2Mbskbh1D?p=preview

In a nut shell, I have the code listed below in my index.html

```
<div data-ng-controller="addCtrl" data-ng-include="'app/views/add.html'" />   
<div data-ng-controller="editCtrl" data-ng-include="'app/views/edit.html'" />
```

I have two buttons, one that shows the add.html, the other edit.html via `$broadcast`
With the current order, add works, but edit doesn't. If I flip the order, eg:

```
<div data-ng-controller="editCtrl" data-ng-include="'app/views/edit.html'" />
<div data-ng-controller="addCtrl" data-ng-include="'app/views/add.html'" />
```

Then edit works, but add doesn't.
This might have to do with why my previous question was screwing up, but not sure: ["Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" but another is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602334/element-is-not-currently-visible-and-so-may-not-be-interacted-with-but-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that angular can not part `<div />` notation.

Expanding to `<div ...></div>` works.