# How to check what is causing a web element to be invisible to Python Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium

I am trying to use Python Selenium to click a button on a webpage, but Selenium is giving exception "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

The DOM structure is quite simple:

`<body style="overflow: hidden;">
...
    <div aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; ...">
        ...
        <button id="button-aaa" aria-hidden="true" style="...">
        ...
    </div>
...
</body>`

I have searched Google and Stackoverflow. Some users say Selenium cannot click a web element which is under a parent node with `overflow: hidden`. But surprisingly, I found that Selenium is able to click some other buttons which are also under a parent node with `overflow: hidden`.

Anyway, I have tried to use driver.execute_script to change the `<body>` style to `overflow: none`, but Selenium is still unable to click this button.

I have also tried to change the button's `aria-hidden="true"` to `aria-hidden="false"`, but Selenium still failed to click.

I have also tried to add `"display: block;"` to the button's style, and tried all different combination of style changes, but Selenium still failed to click.

I have used this commands to check the button: `buttonelement.is_displayed()`. It always returns False no matter what style I change in the DOM. The button is clearly visually visible in the Firefox browser, and it is clickable and functioning. By using the Chrome console, I am able to select the button using ID.

May I know how can I check what is causing a web element to be invisible to Python Selenium?

Comment: This question will be difficult to answer without a concrete example to work with.

Comment: You can get page source using something like this:  `browser.get(raw_input("Enter URL: "))
html_source = browser.page_source
`, then proceed from there.

Comment: afaik, overflow can get only five values (overflow: auto | hidden | scroll | visible | inherit). Try `visible`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich Thank you very much!! Changing the style to `overflow: visible` solved the problem! I have trouble-shoot this problem for so many days. You help me a lot. Actually I copy the codes from this Stackoverflow post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17684455/1460655). Not sure why `bbbco` use `overflow: none` in his codes. Anyway, please put your comment in the answer section so that I can mark it as accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: hi i am not sure how to do the same thing with selenium java (java script)can you please help me 1. how  to change the button's aria-hidden="true" to aria-hidden="false",2.how to  change the button's aria-hidden="true" to aria-hidden="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow takes only one of five values `(overflow: auto | hidden | scroll | visible | inherit)`. Use `visible`